# ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone >= boolean Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s)

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Am trying to execute a Named Query using JPA. Query has to search and pull the records based on criteria of the query. Criteria is query should pull the records between specific given times(Records between From and To Dates provided) and name of the Application.

Query works fine, when executed in Postgresql. But, through JPA it gives error while executing the query

```
Here is my Query in PostgreSQL :
SELECT  auditLog.busn_sys_id            
        , sourceSystem.busn_sys_full_nm     
        , auditLog.purge_ts                 
        , auditLog.rec_purge_cnt            

FROM    rec_ret.rec_rtn_purge_adt                   auditLog
LEFT    JOIN    gbl_dm.gbl_busn_sys_dm              sourceSystem            on (auditLog.busn_sys_id = sourceSystem.busn_sys_id)

    WHERE   (auditLog.purge_ts BETWEEN '2019-08-19' AND '2019-08-25')
      and  sourceSystem.busn_sys_full_nm like 'PROFILE' 

    order by auditLog.busn_sys_id ;
```

Here is my JPA implementation to get Results List

```
try{

            Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT auditLog.busn_sys_id, sourceSystem.busn_sys_full_nm, auditLog.purge_ts, auditLog.rec_purge_cnt " +
                    "FROM rec_ret.rec_rtn_purge_adt auditLog " +
                    "LEFT JOIN gbl_dm.gbl_busn_sys_dm sourceSystem on (auditLog.busn_sys_id = sourceSystem.busn_sys_id) " +
                    "WHERE (auditLog.purge_ts BETWEEN auditLog.purge_ts = :requestedFrom AND auditLog.purge_ts = :requestedTo) " +
                    //"WHERE (auditLog.purge_ts BETWEEN requestedFrom = (?) AND requestedTo = (?)) " +
                    "and  sourceSystem.busn_sys_full_nm = :sourceSystem " +
                    "order by auditLog.busn_sys_id ");

            query.setParameter("requestedFrom",auditLogCriteria.getFromDate());
            query.setParameter("requestedTo",auditLogCriteria.getToDate());
            query.setParameter("sourceSystem",auditLogCriteria.getSourceSystem());;

            query.executeUpdate();
            return query.getResultList();


        }catch (Exception e){
            logger.error("Fetching of logs failed with message : " + e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
```

Here is my implementation of Entity/Model class code

```
@NotNull (message = "Name of the Source System should be entered")
    private String sourceSystem;

    @NotNull (message = "Specify FromDate to filter records")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss[.SSS]")
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime fromDate;

    @NotNull (message = "Specify ToDate to filter records")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss[.SSS]")
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime toDate;
\\ Getters and Setters
```

Here is the Error :

```
Hibernate: SELECT auditLog.busn_sys_id, sourceSystem.busn_sys_full_nm, auditLog.purge_ts, auditLog.rec_purge_cnt FROM rec_ret.rec_rtn_purge_adt auditLog LEFT JOIN gbl_dm.gbl_busn_sys_dm sourceSystem on (auditLog.busn_sys_id = sourceSystem.busn_sys_id) WHERE (auditLog.purge_ts BETWEEN auditLog.purge_ts = ? AND auditLog.purge_ts = ?) and  sourceSystem.busn_sys_full_nm = ? order by auditLog.busn_sys_id 

[ERROR] 2019-08-29 10:02:00.558 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone >= boolean
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 267
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1593)
```

So, result should be all the records matching with the criteria has to be returned as a response to JSON request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your JPA query looks wrong:

```
BETWEEN auditLog.purge_ts = :requestedFrom AND auditLog.purge_ts = :requestedTo
```

I think it should be:

```
BETWEEN :requestedFrom AND :requestedTo
```